# Python Selenium show geckodriver version

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

How can I find out which version of geckodriver I use?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Not sure if the new one is used or the old one when I use:

```
sys.path.append(self.driver_dir)
```

Thanks in advance

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: I place the geckodriver in the same directory where my code is. That way there is no confusion about the version.

Answer (score 0):

You can get capabilities of driver by below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print driver.capabilities
```

It will print driver related info in dictionary form, which would also have info about driver version.

Comment: It should be noted that driver.capabilities will show the browser version but not the geckodriver version.

Comment: For chrome it shows driver version too.
{'chromedriverVersion': u'2.37.544315,  u'version': u'69.0.3497.100'}

Answer (score 0):

This question is also found here: [How do you get the geckodriver version from python selenium firefox webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359334/how-do-you-get-the-geckodriver-version-from-python-selenium-firefox-webdriver)

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox
print(browser.capabilities)
```

The output contains 'moz:geckodriverVersion' where the version can be found.